# Using Graphviz to create a graph of interconnected circles

Tags: graphviz

I want to use Graphviz to create a graph of multiple centred circular layouts, similar to those created by the old "they rule" app online.

With this sample input:

```
graph G {
   "Group 1" -- { "Bob" "Andy" "Chris" "George" "Herbert" "Fred" }
   "Group 2" -- { "Bob" "Diana" "Egbert" "Fred" "George" "Ian" }
   "Group 3" -- { "Diana" "Ian" "Chris" "Jasper" }
}
```

`circo` produces close to the correct output, but creates an unnecessary large empty circle in the middle of the diagram, where three connected layouts would be neater. Both `neato` and `twopi` tend to overlap nodes or do not hold the clusters together.

Is there any graphviz option, or a different package, that can use a `circo` style layout within the clusters then connect the shared nodes in the clusters `neato` style? I tried using subgraphs in `circo` or using `packMode="clust"` but it was still disregarded in favor of fitting everything to a large circle.

Comment: There are no clusters (as defined in graphviz) in your example, and, if I remember correctly, circo doesn't support clusters for layout. If there were to define clusters - to which cluster would "Bob" belong to ? What are the "they rule app" layouts like ? Also, you may try adding `overlap=false` with neato which eliminates the overlapping of the nodes.

Comment: Bob would be between the two clusters he is part of, on a linking line.